# pip installs Python modules in python 2.7 rather than 3.4

Tags: package-management, python, python3

I am trying to use pip to download and install python packages.  I am using Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

I attempted `sudo pip install paperclip`, for example.

It gets installed to `/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

I would want to have it installed in `/usr/bin/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`

Guidance would be appreciated

Comment: pip probably points to pip27 or something similar, isn't there a pip3 or pip34 command?

Answer (score 4):

Install Pip for Python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

And then use it to install packages into Python3

```
sudo pip3 install paperclip
```

Answer (score 1):

Install pip for python3 by running

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

And then use it for installing the required package.

```
pip3 install package_name
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did some additional research, and installing setuptools and running easy_install on the package solved the problem for me.